# C++ - Map of Vectors of Smart Pointers - All inherited from the same base class

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, vector, stl

I've got this Map in my Entity-Component-System:

```
std::map<u_int32_t, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>> _componentMap;
```

The `u_int32_t` is the key to a vector of components. There can be multiple instances of the same component. (That's why there's a vector).

Now I would like to have a templated getter-function that returns a Vector of an inherited type:

```
template<class T> inline const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> & getVector() const
{
     u_int32_t key = getKey<T>();
     return static_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>>(_componentMap.count(key) ? _componentMap.at(key) : _emptyComponentVec);
}
```

I know that this doesn't work, since `std::vectors` of different types are completely unrelated and I cannot cast between them. I would also like to avoid allocating a new vector every time this function is called.

But how I can I get the desired behaviour? When the the components are added I can create an `std::vector` of the desired derived type.

The question could also be: How can I have an `std::map` containing different types of `std::vector`?

For any solutions I can not link against boost, though if absolutely needed, I could integrate single headers of boost.

Comment: Wonder if a `std::tuple<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<TComponents>>...>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a bit further? I'm not quite the C++ expert. I've used tuples, but I don't see how they would solve it. If it works, I'm also open for changing my data structure.

Comment: I mean, something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7da105926698f0c).

Comment: Ah I see, But that would require to name all possible components when initializing....which is also not really desirable.

Comment: If you can use some *range library*, you may do a* view* or your components vector without allocation.

Comment: Use `std::map<u_int32_t, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>>> _componentMap;`, but you have to "remember" what type you stored in what element and retrieve it based on that knowledge. The way you "remember" is to wrap it in a class that manages those casting for you.

Comment: FYI, C++11 has `uint32_t` which you can use instead of the custom `u_int32_t`.

Comment: @EissaN. `<std::shared_ptr<void>>` sounds dangerous - isn't the point of `std::shared_ptr<Component>` ensuring that the vector participates in the lifetime of `Component`? I don't see how that would be possible with `std::shared_ptr<void>`.

Comment: @user4815162342 It's not dangerous, specially if you manage everything inside a wrapper class.

Comment: What operations on the vector do you want to perform, *exactly*?  Just way to iterate over the components?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to use reinterpret_cast:

```
    template<class T> inline std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> * getVector() const
    {
        auto key = getKey<T>();
        return reinterpret_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> *>( (_componentMap.count(key) ? _componentMap.at(key).get() : const_cast<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> *>(&_emptyComponentSharedPtrVec)) );
    }
```

It's not very pretty but it does work fine and it fulfills all requirements.

Comment: It's Undefined Behavior.
The only reason this works is pure luck.
But like all UBs, it might cease to work at any moment, for any reason.
And by Murphy's Law, it will fail at the worst moment possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude implementation of a solution I have in mind for this problem. Of course, there are many rooms to refine the code, but hopefully it conveys my idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void f() const = 0;
};

class A : public Base {
public:
    static const int type = 0;
    explicit A(int a) : a_(a) {}
    void f() const { cout << "calling A::f" << endl;}
    int a_;
};
class B : public Base {
public:
    static const int type = 1;
    explicit B(int a) : a_(a) {}
    void f() const { cout << "calling B::f" << endl;}
    int a_;
};

class MapWrapper {
public:
    template<class T>
    void append(int a, vector<T> const& vec) {
        types_[a] = T::type;
        my_map_[a] = make_shared<vector<T>>(vec);
    }
    template<class T>
    vector<T> const& get(int a) const {
        return *static_pointer_cast<vector<T>>( my_map_.at(a) );
    }
    map<int, shared_ptr<void>> const& get_my_map() const {
        return my_map_;
    }
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> get_base(int a) const {
        vector<shared_ptr<Base>> ret;
        switch(types_.at(a)) {
            case 0: {
                auto const vec = get<A>(a);
                for(auto v : vec)
                    ret.push_back(make_shared<A>(v));
                break;  
            }
            case 1: {
                auto const vec = get<B>(a);
                for(auto v : vec)
                    ret.push_back(make_shared<B>(v));
                break;  
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    map<int, shared_ptr<void>> my_map_;
    map<int, int> types_;
};  

int main() {
    MapWrapper map_wrapper;
    map_wrapper.append(10, vector<A>{A(2), A(4)});
    map_wrapper.append(20, vector<B>{B(5), B(7), B(9)});

    for(auto const& w : map_wrapper.get_my_map())
        for(auto v : map_wrapper.get_base(w.first))
            v->f();

    for(auto const& x: map_wrapper.get<A>(10))
        cout << x.a_ << " ";
    cout << endl;

    for(auto const& x: map_wrapper.get<B>(20))
        cout << x.a_ << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I see that correctly, you store void shared_pointers to std::vector of different types in the map, and when asked for them you cast them back into their respective types?

Comment: I tried to implement your solution today and I found a major problem that I didn't see before: If the map only has a shared_ptr to void, I can no longer iterate over all Components using functions of the base class. For example when en entity enters the scene I call onEnter on all its components. Does this also work somehow with your solution and I don't see it yet?

Comment: @keyboard I am not clear on the problem you have encountered. Can you be more specific and perhaps give an example?

Comment: If we have a map of vectors of Component, we can iterate over all Components and call a function that the base calls Component has. But, if we have a map of void (and in fact there's multiple vectors of different types behind it), we can never iterate of all components and call some base-function classes. I hope I explained it better this time.

Comment: @keyboard Well, you need to cast it properly every time you want to use it. For example, `map_wrapper.get<B>(20)` means get the map element corresponding to key `20` and cast it as `vector<B>`. So, the return type is a vector and that's why I could write a loop like `for(auto const& x: map_wrapper.get<B>(20)) ...`

Comment: Yes exactly, but what do I do if I'm at a stage where I do not know the type of every single vector in the map, but I know that all vectors contain pointers to objects derived from Component? There might be 10 different subclasses of Component, but I just want to iterate over all objects treating them as their base class, Component.

Comment: @keyboard This can be done by keeping the track of the types of the derived classes in the `MapWrapper` class. I updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. Well, yes I could create a new vector when being asked for the base class, but that costs performance. I have to call these operations very often (and on mobile devices), so performance is critical. It also seems to require to write code for every single possible type which is also undesirable. There must be a cleaner solution. All objects are of a type derived from Component. There must be a way to use them as their actual type, and also being able to iterate over them as their base class - Component.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class It>
struct range_view {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
  using reference = decltype(*std::declval<It const&>());
  reference operator[](std::size_t n) const
  {
    return b[n];
  }
  bool empty() const { return begin()==end(); }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  reference front() const {
    return *begin();
  }
  reference back() const {
    return *std::prev(end());
  }
  template<class O>
  range_view( O&& o ):
    b(std::begin(o)), e(std::end(o))
  {}
};
```

this is a quick range view.  It can be improved.

Now all you need to do is write a pseudo-random-access iterator that converts its arguments.  So it takes a random access iterator over a type T, then does some operation F to return a type U.  It forwards all other operations.

The `map` then stores `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`.  The gettor returns a `range_view< converting_iterator<spBase2spDerived> >`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting, but it's kind of above my head at the moment. I still don't understand what a range view really is (despite having read a few explanations)

Comment: A range view is like a pointer, but instead of pointing at one element, it points at a range.  It does not support adding or removing elements ob the container, just looking at them.

Comment: Okay, I see. Unfortunately I still have no idea how to use it, I don't know how to write a pseudo-random-access iterator. I'd also like to avoid having to allocate a range_view every time getVector is called. The overhead is probably minimal but I've got the feeling that there must be an easier solution.